# Generators in ES6 and the working mechanism of yield

Tags: ecmascript-6, generator

```
 function* help(){
       const aa = yield 'no_help';
         return aa;
}
const a = help();
a.next()// valid output
a.next('helping hand')// valid output
```

In the doc I have read yield consumes one next call completly so my confusion is that then how can we call next method again as shown above with some value inside it

Comment: What's your goal? I don't think you've fully grasped the utility of generators with the code you've posted here.

Comment: right now I want to understand the code working mechanism which I have posted as it conflict with theoretical concept

Comment: Which theoretical concept are you speaking of, precisely? It's quite unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `yield` you "split up" the function into multiple parts that can be executed seperately (but only in order):

```
 function* help(){
   // part 1starts
   //....
   const aa = yield 'no_help'; // part 1 ends
   // part 2 starts
   // ...
     return aa; // part 2 ends
 }
```

If you call `a.next()` part 1 gets executed until the `yield` and the intermediate result `'no_help'` gets returned to the call. Then you call `a.next('your helping hand')` that will execute part 2 and you will get back what the function returns. As there is no third part calling `a.next()` again won't work.